# How to setup Titiler for customized root_path to be used on an existing Nginx config

Tags: python, nginx, fastapi, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Given an instance of Geonode, the Nginx uses this [config](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-project/blob/master/docker/nginx/geonode.conf.envsubst)
I would like to add the upstream of a [titiler](https://github.com/developmentseed/titiler)
I have the compose file:

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  titiler:
    image: ghcr.io/developmentseed/titiler:latest
    container_name: titiler
    environment:
      - PORT=8081
      - WORKERS_PER_CORE=1
      - TITILER_API_ROOT_PATH=/api/v1/titiler
```

with the new nginx config

```
(...)
location /api/v1/titiler {
    set $upstream titiler:8081;
    proxy_pass http://$upstream;
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

The problem is that, inside the nginx container when I tried to `curl titiler:8081/api/v1/titiler`  i got `curl titiler:8081/api/v1/titiler {"detail":"Not Found"}`, the issue seems a problem of the titiler doesnt use the given ROOT_PATH, my question is, since it is obviously a problem of titiler, more precisely [fastapi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/), is there a way to configure titiler on an existing server?

inside the container of titiler

```
from titiler.application.main import api_settings
print(api_settings.root_path)
```

I got "/api/v1/titiler"

I have describe above the step I did but couldnt get any progress

Comment: This has been discussed [here](https://github.com/developmentseed/titiler/discussions/650) but somehow it doesnt work in my case.

Comment: it has been solved adding `rewrite ^/api/v1/titiler(.*)$ $1 break;`

Answer (score 0):

````
location /api/v1/titiler {
    set $upstream titiler:8081;
    rewrite ^/api/v1/titiler(.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://$upstream;
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).